# Unable to capture result of ls -la with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.x

I am trying to capture the output when I execute a custom command using `Popen`:

```
import subprocess

def exec_command():
    command = "ls -la" # will be replaced by my custom command 
    result = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    print(result)

exec_command()
```

I get an `OSError` with following stacktrace:

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please let me know what I would need to use.

Note: The stacktrace shows the code was executed in Python 2.7, but I got the same error running with Python 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running without `shell=True` (which you are doing, correctly; `shell=True` is dangerous), you should pass your command as a sequence of the command and the arguments, not a single string. Fixed code is:

```
def exec_command():
    command = ["ls", "-la"]  # list of command and argument
    ... rest of code unchanged ...
```

If you had user input involved for some of the arguments, you'd just insert it into the `list`:

```
def exec_command(somedirfromuser):
    command = ["ls", "-la", somedirfromuser]
```

Note: If your commands are sufficiently simple, I'd recommend avoiding `subprocess` entirely. `os.listdir` and `os.stat` (or on Python 3.5+, `os.scandir` alone) can get you the same info as `ls -la` in a more programmatically usable form without the need to parse it, and likely faster than launching an external process and communicating with it via a pipe.

Comment: my actual command is a file copy command which looks something like "exec -profile profile_name -copy file_path". So would that be ["exec", "-profile", "profile_name", "-copy", "file_path"] ?. Thanks!

Comment: @pythondev: Well, if the `profile_name` and `file_path` arguments were Python level variables, you wouldn't quote them, so it would be `["exec", "-profile", profile_name, "-copy", file_path]`, but yeah, you have the right idea.